# Python TelegramBot save contacts

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Hello i have a code this code sends the contact

```
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=False)
    reg_button = types.KeyboardButton(text="...", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(reg_button)
    keyboard.row('...')
    response = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'...',
                                reply_markup=keyboard)
    print(response.contact)  # response.contact = None here
```

Why save for contact in file or database. Help please :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#bot sends the received data to the channel
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact','location'])  def send_welcome(message):
   first_name = message.from_user.first_name.decode("utf-8")
   user_id = message.from_user.id
   username = message.chat.username
   chat_id = message.chat.id
   if message.contact:
       pn = message.contact.phone_number
       cf = message.contact.first_name
       bot.send_message(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID, "#contact [{0}](https://telegram.me/{1})".format(user_id, username), parse_mode="Markdown", disable_web_page_preview=True)
       bot.send_contact(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID,  phone_number=pn, first_name=cf)
   if message.location:
       bot.send_message(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID, "#location [{0}](https://telegram.me/{1})".format(user_id, username), parse_mode="Markdown", disable_web_page_preview=True)
       bot.send_location(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID,  message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude)
```